# Knockout nested observable comparison to a boolean

Tags: knockout.js, boolean

The visible binding is evaluating to the wrong value despite all possible combinations of paranthesis!

My ViewModel is as below:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.current_convo = ko.observable(new Message(false));
} 

function Message (val) {
    this.archived = ko.observable(val);
}
```

And my HTML reads

```
<button data-bind="visible: (current_convo().archived == false)">Archive</button>
```

I also tried using

```
<button data-bind="visible: !(current_convo().archived)">Archive</button>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something but unable to put my finger on it!

Answer (score 2):

The first won't work because `archived` is an observable -- it might evaluate to `false`, but it's not itself `false`. The second won't work, again because you're negating the observable, not its value.

This should work:

```
<button data-bind="visible: !current_convo().archived()">Archive</button>
```

Comment: Tried that too Ismail. That doesn't either. Also tried !(current_convo().archived())

Comment: Well, that works for me. Post your complete code, e.g. where you call `applyBindings`? And how are you testing whether it works?